# Refreshing Update Panel Igot a problem if the user is writing at that time

Tags: asp.net, refresh, chat

Im trying to make a web chat using ajax control tool kit. There is a script mannager, the update panel and the timer.

I inserted the textbox for showing every text that is introduced by the users, the text for writing and the send button are out. It works great but if im writing some text in the exact moment of refreshing time (winch happends a lot because its every 3 sec) it does not let me write correctly cause the textbox kind of blink and you miss a letter. So, wich is the correct method for doing this without lossing the fluidity of the writing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create 2 textboxes: one for input and anther for output. The one for input should be placed outside the update panel, so it never will be refreshed. Also you will need to add this textbox or its send button as a trigger to your update panel. Similar to this [example](http://asyncpostback.com/02_UpdatePanel/03_UpdatePanelTriggers.aspx)

Here is the code I tried and it works:

Aspx:

```
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="2000" Enabled="True">
        </asp:Timer>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Clicked" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And C#:

```
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    protected void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Label1.Text = String.Format("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), TextBox1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: yes, I put 2 text boxes in that way, one inside update panel and one outside, but the blink still happend, and with the event that send the text im not using triguers but Im not having problem with it, the issue is just about the refreshing. Please help. Tnks

Comment: I added some code to my previous post. If the control is outside update panel there should not be any blinks, may be you do something else that affects you control?

Comment: You should use that trigger on you button outside your update panel, otherwise button click event will refresh the whole page.

Comment: Perfect, I just needed the triguer for the timer, now it works how it should be. THANKS!